# how to ensure node-sass and sass-loader versions are compatible?

Tags: node.js, node-sass, sass-loader

My Nodejs version is v16.16.0 and npm version is 8.11.0.

[image]

and errors keep coming saying

[image]

Is there any way to upgrade sass-loader?
(Also, when npm run serve is run this error comes up

Syntax Error: Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.)

Comment: Don't use the (deprecated) node-sass at all?

Comment: IOW, what @jonrsharpe is saying: `npm uninstall node-sass; npm install --save-dev sass` and you're good.

Answer (score 8):

## Dont use `node-sass`

`node-sass` has been depricated. So you will have to use the new version, which is `sass`

You can do this to fix all compatibility errors related to `node-sass`

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked beautifully for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your **package.json** file change the dependency from `"node-sass": "^7.0.1"` to `"sass":"^1.22.10"` and then install this dependency.

Read more here https://github.com/sass/node-sass